# when we only have 6 bits of data on a byte, what do we fill the byte with up to 8?

Tags: byte, bit

When we only have 6 bits of data on a byte, what do we fill the byte with up to 8? In the picture below the important data , it's only 10 03 , but what is the science behind, how that neimportant bits are choosen ? What mean [55] or [AA]? I mention 10 03 is a request for diagnosis and 50 03 are a response.

[image]

The communication its on CAN and that it's a trace with CAN DATA .

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what are you talking about, but that looks like a Hex representation.

1 byte -> 2 hex characters -> 8 bits.  AA -> 10, 10 in decimal -> 1010 1010 (binary)

explicit bits are always the right side or LSB (less significant bits)

example, in javascript regular integer is 32 bit long.

`

```
const number = 0b1010 //binary
 const hexNumber = 0xA // hex
```

`  -> 10 in decimal. As you can see we have only tell the less significant 4 bits. every other bit is an implicit 0